# Custom Linear Layout Child not showing

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

i tried to create custom linear layout that have dynamic height and width = height. The custom layout is fine, but the child view not showing at my custom linear layout. i tried some way to fix it, but still cant solve it.

```
public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public CustomLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(height, height);

    }
}
```

this is the xml that contain my custom linear layout. the child view not showing.

```
<com.example.admin.antriclient.CustomLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_nomor_antrian"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >
        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:id="@+id/service_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Teller"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="false"
            autofit:minTextSize="12sp"
            />
        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:id="@+id/nomor_antrian"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="T21"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            autofit:minTextSize="12sp"
            />

</com.example.admin.antriclient.CustomLinearLayout>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't call the `super` method in `onMeasure()`, you need to handle measuring out each child `View` by calling its `measure()` method appropriately. Otherwise, the child `View`s will end up with 0 width and height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem is because i didnt call the super.onMeasure() method. Thanks to Mike M.

my class should be like this

```
public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public CustomLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
        //int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        //setMeasuredDimension(height, height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to add a LayoutInflater for it to show

```
public class SidebarLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private static final String TAG = "SidebarLayout";

    public SidebarLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);    
    }

    public SidebarLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);       
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sidebar, this);
    }

    public SidebarLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);      
    }
}
```

```
<com.example.a3danimationtester.SidebarLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_sidebar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layout_topbar" />
```